# Solving polynomial equation with calculus

Tags: calculus, polynomials

I saw a question stating that

Let $f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $5 $.

$ x-1|f(x)+1 $ and $x+1|f(x)-1$ . Find $f(x)$ without using calculus.

And because I am not good at calculus , I was not able to solve the question with or without using calculus.

Please help me in solving it.

A hint for how to start could work.

Comment: The two conditions are equivalent to $f(1)=-1$ and $f(-1)=1$ but that's not enough to determine the polynomial univocally.

Comment: But the question is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Followup on previous comment:

> The two conditions are equivalent to $f(1)=−1$ and $f(−1)=1$ but that's not enough to determine the polynomial univocally.

Let the quintic be $f(x) = ax^5+bx^4+cx^3+dx^2+ex+f$, then the two conditions give:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
a+b+c+d+e+f & = -1 \\
-a+b-c+d-e+f &= 1
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Adding and subtracting the two equations:

$$
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
a+c+e &= -1 \\
b+d+f & = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

The above give the necessary and sufficient relations that the coefficients of $f(x)$ must satisfy, but do not determine $f(x)$ univocally. For example, all of the following satisfy the given conditions:

- $f(x) = -x^5$
- $f(x) = x^5 - x^3 - x$
- $f(x) = x^5 + 3 x^4 - x^3 - 5 x^2 - x + 2$
- $f(x) = a x^5 + b x^4 + cx^3 +d x^2 - (a+c+1)x - b-d \quad \text{for} \;\forall a,b,c,d$